# float-label doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

My float-label doesn't work on Firefox. Its all ok on Chrome, like you can see on the prints.

My code is like this:

```
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
                <span class="ui-float-label">
                    <textarea pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="consulta.dsDiagnostico1" name="dsDiagnostico1" id="diagnostico1" style="resize:none"
                          rows="4" cols="100"
                          class="form-control" maxLength="4000"></textarea>
                    <label for="diagnostico1">Diagnóstico 1</label>
                </span>
            </div>
```

This is the component:
[Component Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvJ4w.png)

After typing in Chrome: 
[Chrome typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MURH0.png)

After typing in Firefox:
[Firefox typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLcyG.png)

Anyone knows a nice solution that doesn't "static" the label and allow the correctly function of float-label on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same problem I found a solution for this problem, do this in your css file and the labels will work in firefox to. this is a workaround but for the moment there is no fix delivered by the team of PrimeNG

```
.ui-float-label>input:focus~label, .ui-float-label>input.ui-state-filled~label, .ui-float-label>.ui-inputwrapper-focus~label, .ui-float-label>.ui-inputwrapper-filled~label { top: -.75em; font-size: 12px; }
.ui-float-label>textarea:focus~label, .ui-float-label>textarea.ui-state-filled~label, .ui-float-label>.ui-textareawrapper-focus~label, .ui-float-label>.ui-textareawrapper-filled~label { top: -.75em; font-size: 12px; }
```